# ¿Cómo traspasar variables en multiproccessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una función que toma unos valores, y luego quiero ejecutarla pero que si pasa de un cierto tiempo el programa la detiene. Leyendo me he encontrado con `multiprocessing` y en principio me sirve. El único inconveniente es que las variables globales que tengo en la función principal no las detecta y no sé como solucionarlo ya que las necesito para escribir en un `txt` con ellas. Como la función es grande, voy a poner un ejemplo chorra, pero que es lo que busco:

```
def prueba():
    global n
    
    n=5

if __name__ == '__main__':
      # Se ejecuta la función
      p = multiprocessing.Process(target=prueba, name="Prueba")
      p.start()

      # Le damos un tiempo estimado
      time.sleep(10)

      # Terminamos la función si se pasa del tiempo
      p.terminate()

      # Limpiamos
      p.join()

Informacion=[]    
Informacion.append(n)
with open("Carperta/Destino","w") as escribir:
escribir.write(str(Informacion[0]))
```

Y aquí me salta el error de que la `n` pues no tiene valor y por ende, `Informacion` tampoco.
¿Alguna idea?
Gracias

Comment: Parece que te falta un `n = None` al comienzo de todo. Al poner `None` detectaras de inmediato cualquier intento de usar `n` antes de que esté inicializada.

Comment: Disculpa, podrias decir donde? He probado en varios sitios y luego al final lo que me devuelve la n es None y no 5

Comment: Si te devuelve `None`quiere decir que aún no esta actualizada por la función. Tienes que chequear antes de usarla que sea distinta de `None`.

Comment: Es que para simplificar, probé lo que me propusiste con la función que puse de ejemplo y no me da el resultado esperado

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo con la documentación de Python, para transpasar información entre procesos se usa `Queue` o `Pipes`.

La solución más simple es crear una cola en el proceso principal y ejecutar el sub-proceso pasando la cola como argumento, para usarla para recuperar el valor producido.

La ventaja adicional es que el proceso principal puede esperar con timeout en la cola. Así obtendra el valor tan pronto se produzca, y se producirá una excepción si la cola no produce el valor en el tiempo requerido.

En este ejemplo, puse un `time.sleep` en la función `prueba` para poder chequear distintos escenarios.

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def prueba(cola):
    time.sleep(4)
    cola.put(5)
```

En el `main` creamos una cola:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cola = multiprocessing.Queue()
```

y lanzamos el segundo proceso pasando la cola:

```
    # Se ejecuta la función
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=prueba, name="Prueba", args=(cola,))
    p.start()
```

Aquí esperamos hasta 10 segundos para obtener un resultado desde la cola. Si todo está bien, procesamos el resultado.

```
    try:
        valor = cola.get(block=True, timeout= 10)

        Informacion = [valor]
        with open("multi.txt", "w") as escribir:
            print("escribir", valor)
            escribir.write(str(Informacion[0]))
```

Si da timeout, se ejecuta el `except`. Como el subproceso se quedo colgado, lo terminamos.

```
    except:
        # Terminamos la función si se pasa del tiempo
        print("Timeout")
    p.terminate()

    # Limpiamos
    p.join()
```

#### Código completo

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def prueba(cola):
    time.sleep(4)
    cola.put(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cola = multiprocessing.Queue()
    # Se ejecuta la función
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=prueba, name="Prueba", args=(cola,))
    p.start()

    try:
        valor = cola.get(block=True, timeout= 10)

        Informacion = [valor]
        with open("multi.txt", "w") as escribir:
            print("escribir", valor)
            escribir.write(str(Informacion[0]))

    except:
        # Terminamos la función si se pasa del tiempo
        print("Timeout")
    p.terminate()

    # Limpiamos
    p.join()
```